# get last month first date and last date in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I am creating a batch file to execute some exe file. In that exe i need to specify first date(mm/dd/yyyy) and last day(mm/dd/yyyy) of last month.

```
@echo off
start "Testing" "c:\Program Files\app-cmd\bin\admincmd\imagelist -d 08/01/2015 -e 01/09/2015 > c:\test.txt"
```

**Imagelist** is an exe file where I need to pass value in **-d** and **-e** parameter.
I will add this script in schedule task so, it will run as schedule.

I can't use powershell as machine is win server 2003.

Please advise.

Comment: Thanks i am checking now. ah its about javascript.

Comment: Still not sure what your problem is. Do you want to get the current date as mm/dd/yyyy to pass it to the script?

Comment: no i am trying to get last month first and last date in mm/dd/yyyy to pass it to script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the date format on your system is MM/DD/YYYY as shown by `date /t` command:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=/ tokens=1,3" %%a in ("%date%") do set month=%%a& set year=%%b

if %month:~0,1%==0 set month=%month:~1%
set /a month-=1 && if !month!==0 set month=12&set /a year-=1

if not !month!==2 (
    set /a last_day="31 - (month - 1) %% 7 %% 2"
) else (
    set /a y4="year %% 4" & if !y4!==0 (
        set /a y100="year %% 100" & if not !y100!==0 set is_leap_year=1
        set /a y400="year %% 400" & if !y400!==0 set is_leap_year=1
    )
    if "!is_leap_year!"=="1" (set last_day=29) else set last_day=28
)

set month=0!month!
start "Testing" "c:\Program Files\app-cmd\bin\admincmd\imagelist" ^
    -d !month:~-2!/01/!year! -e !month:~-2!/!last_day!/!year! > c:\test.txt
```

The code detects leap years as `(year % 4 == 0) && ((year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))` for February and uses `31 - (month - 1) % 7 % 2` for other months.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: One question. It is giving me current month dates. I am looking for last month.

Comment: I can't put that way. Script should need to get the value for last month. in this case sep is current month then script should output the result for aug

Comment: I think there is a problem with %year% because it is not giving any output.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    call :getLastMonthLimits start end
    echo %start% - %end%

    goto :eof

:getLastMonthLimits startDateReturnVar endDateReturnVar
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    for %%t in ("%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%.rpt") do (
        for /f "tokens=4,7" %%a in ('
            ^>nul makecab /f nul /d RptFileName^="%%~ft" /V0  
            ^& type "%%~ft" ^| find "MakeCAB Report:"
        ') do (
            set /a "jan=1,feb=2,mar=3,apr=4,may=5,jun=6,jul=7,aug=8,sep=9,oct=10,nov=11,dec=12"
            set /a "m=(%%a+10) %% 12 + 1", "y=%%b-m/12", "d=30+((m+m/8) %% 2)", "m+=100"
            if /i %%a==mar set /a "d=d-2 +(3-y %% 4)/3 -(99-y %% 100)/99 +(399-y %% 400)/399"
            set /a "d+=100"
        ) 
    ) & del "%%~ft"
    endlocal & set "%~1=%m:~-2%/01/%y%" & set "%~2=%m:~-2%/%d:~-2%/%y%"
    goto :eof
```

This uses a simplified version of the [getDate function by carlos](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=29758#p29758) to get the date in a locale independent format (I prefer to use `robocopy` for it, but it is not a native tool in 2003). The rest are just arithmetic operations to calculate the month limits.

**edited** For the `robocopy` version (instead of the `makecab` to retrieve the date in locale independent format), just in case someone could need it

```dos
@echo off

    call :getLastMonthLimits start end
    echo %start% - %end%

    goto :eof

:getLastMonthLimits startDateReturnVar endDateReturnVar
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/ " %%a in ('robocopy "|" . /njh ^| find "|"') do (
        set /a "m=((1%%b-100)+10) %% 12 + 1", "y=%%a-m/12", "d=30+((m+m/8) %% 2)", "m+=100"
        if %%b==03 set /a "d=d-2 +(3-y %% 4)/3 -(99-y %% 100)/99 +(399-y %% 400)/399"
        set /a "d+=100"
    )
    endlocal & set "%~1=%m:~-2%/01/%y%" & set "%~2=%m:~-2%/%d:~-2%/%y%"
    goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. wOxxOm answer is more suitable in my scenario.   Voted up.

Comment: Thanks for this. Worked great for a script I needed to write. Especially the additional edit as the original version (using makecab) didn't work with a schedule task (although could be the user that was set to run the task as well).